# Python: call individual items from a list stored as a dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I access individual items from a list stored as a dictionary value in python?

```
my_list = ['black','white']

my_dict = {'black':['yes','no'],'white':['maybe','so']}
```

I would like to refer to `my_list` to get values from `my_dict`.

`print(my_dict[my_list[0]])` returns `['yes', 'no']`.

How do I return just 'yes' or just 'maybe'?

Comment: You can chain your indexing: `my_dict[ 'black' ][ 0 ]` will return `'yes'`.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘print(test_dict[test_list[0]][0])’?

Comment: When I try that, it returns    ```print(test_dict[test_list[0][0]]) KeyError: 'b'```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(my_dict[my_list[0]][0]) # prints "yes"
print(my_dict[my_list[0]][1]) # prints "no"
print(my_dict[my_list[1]][0]) # prints "maybe"
print(my_dict[my_list[1]][1]) # prints "so"
```

If you want to use `my_list` use a for loop:

```
for colour in my_list:
    print(my_dict[colour])
```

This prints:

```
["yes", "no"]
["maybe", "so"]
```

Comment: I suggest changing `test_` to `my_` to match the OP's code example.

Comment: His example has to variable names (test_ and my_). I edited OPs post and mine, so it matches.

Comment: Apologies for the mixed variable names. I have accepted the edit. however, the ```print(my_dict[my_list[0][0]])``` suggestion doesn't work. It returns ```KeyError: 'b'```. 'b' is the first letter of the first item in my_list.

Comment: @NWWPA, you have to put the last [0] after the bracket. `my_dict[my_list[0]][0]`

Comment: Oh Im sorry thats was a typo caused by me. That shouldn't happen in answer, glad you guys figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

print(my_dict[my_list[0]][0]) returns the first element from the first dictionary entry value, that is "yes".